# Overlays not rendering

Tags: sxa

I created `overlay content` and added `Rich Text` component to it but when I preview it I see nothing rendered. as I added a component in the main placeholder.
Is there any thing I missed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have datasource item for your  component?

Comment: yes, I added data source to my comonent and variant also.

Comment: Did you check the Final Layout? You are on Shared Layout tab in that picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the content inside the `overlay` placeholder instead of the `main` placeholder.